# how to update multiple rows using php script

Tags: php

i am  inserting data into php script is done .but i have not getting how to update mulitiple rows using php script.

my code format is:

```
  if(is_array($sheetData)){

        //$sql = "INSERT INTO 13_product_id (product_id,ext_product_id) values ";

        $valuesArr = array();
        $flag=0;
        foreach($sheetData as $row){

            if($flag==0 || $row['E']== 'Not Found on build.com'){

                $flag =1;

                continue;

            }
            //print_r($row);
            $product_id =$row['A'];
            $ext_product_id=$row['D'];


           // $valuesArr[] = "('$product_id','$ext_product_id')";

        }
         $sql = "UPDATE 13_product_id SET ext_product_id='$ext_product_id[$row]' WHERE product_id='$product_id[$row]'";
    //$sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
        print_r($sql);
       //mysqli_query($con,$sql) or exit(mysqli_connect_errno()); 
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: If you're already using MySQLi I strongly suggest looking at how to use parametised queries, rather than embedding your values directly into the SQL, it's faster for multiple executions(like you want to do) and it will protected against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your query execution in your loop. Not after it:

```
foreach($sheetData as $row){
    if($flag==0 || $row['E']== 'Not Found on build.com'){
        $flag =1;
        continue;
    }
    $product_id =$row['A'];
    $ext_product_id=$row['D'];

    $sql = "UPDATE 13_product_id SET ext_product_id='$ext_product_id[$row]' WHERE product_id='$product_id[$row]'";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql) or exit(mysqli_errno()); 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(is_array($sheetData)){

    //$sql = "INSERT INTO 13_product_id (ext_product_id,product_id) values (?, ?)";
    $sql = "UPDATE 13_product_id SET ext_product_id= ? WHERE product_id= ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $ext_product_id, $product_id);

    $flag=0;
    foreach($sheetData as $row){

        if($flag==0 || $row['E']== 'Not Found on build.com'){
            $flag =1;
            continue;
        }

        $product_id = $row['A'];
        $ext_product_id = $row['D'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```